# How to apply plugin as Map in Gradle's build script?

Tags: java, plugins, dictionary, groovy, gradle

How can I apply plugin as Map in Gradle? We can use:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()
map.put('plugin', 'java')
apply(map)
```

But when write:

```
apply [plugin:'java']
```

An error occured. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct Groovy syntax to pass a map to a method is `apply the: "map"` or `apply([the: "map"])`. `apply[...]` is subscript syntax (such as when indexing into an array) which isn't defined here.

Answer (score 2):

`apply([plugin:'java'])` or `apply plugin:'java'` will work but not `apply[plugin:'java']`.

`apply`, most likely, is groovy method call and `someMethod[key:value]` is not valid groovy method call.